# Iterating through txt file and adding words to separate lists in Python

Tags: python

I have a text file that has about 50 lines and follows the following format:

```
 immediate     ADC #oper     69    2     2
 absolute      ADC oper      6D    3     4
 etc..
```

What I would like to do is create 6 different lists and add every word in each column on a single line to the separate lists, so that the output becomes this

```
addressing: ['immediate', 'absolute']
symbol: ['ADC', 'ADC']
symbol2: ['#oper', 'oper']
opcode: ['69', '6D']
bytes: ['2', '3']
cycles: ['2', '4']
```

I'm trying to do this in Python but at the moment my code isn't working and adds every word into every list:

```
addressing: ['immidiate', 'ADC', '#oper', '69', '2', '2', 'absolute', 'ADC', 'oper', '6D', '3', '4',]
symbol: ['immidiate', 'ADC', '#oper', '69', '2', '2', 'absolute', 'ADC', 'oper', '6D', '3', '4',]
symbol2: ['immidiate', 'ADC', '#oper', '69', '2', '2', 'absolute', 'ADC', 'oper', '6D', '3', '4',]
opcode: ['immidiate', 'ADC', '#oper', '69', '2', '2', 'absolute', 'ADC', 'oper', '6D', '3', '4',]
bytes: ['immidiate', 'ADC', '#oper', '69', '2', '2', 'absolute', 'ADC', 'oper', '6D', '3', '4',]
cycles: ['immidiate', 'ADC', '#oper', '69', '2', '2', 'absolute', 'ADC', 'oper', '6D', '3', '4',]
```

How can I change the below code so that it produces the output I want?

```
addressing = []
symbol = []
symbol2 = []
opcode = []
bytes = []
cycles = []

index = 1;

for line in f:
    for word in line.split():
        if index == 1:
            addressing.append(word)
            index += 1
            print(index)

        if index == 2:
            symbol.append(word)
            index += 1
            print(index)

        if index == 3:
            symbol2.append(word)
            index += 1
            print(index)

        if index == 4:
            opcode.append(word)
            index += 1
            print(index)

        if index == 5:
            bytes.append(word)
            index += 1
            print(index)

        if index == 6:
            cycles.append(word)
            index += 1
            print(index)
        index = 1
```

Comment: Do you really want 6 separately-named lists? It would be neater to make a dictionary of lists. BTW, you shouldn't use `bytes` as a variable name as that shadows the built-in `bytes` type.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to solve this:

1. The static way which assumes the format will never change and each row will have the same number of values
2. The dynamic way that is flexible to format changes and variable number of items per row assuming that the order of the items remain the same.

I'll detail both ways belows:

**The Static Way:**
Split the line and append using indexes

```
addressing = []
symbol = []
symbol2 = []
opcode = []
bytes = []
cycles = []
for line in f:
    splitted = line.split()
    addressing.append(splitted[0])
    symbol.append(splitted[1])
    symbol2.append(splitted[2])
    opcode.append(splitted[3])
    bytes.append(splitted[4])
    cycles.append(splitted[5])
```

**Dynamic Way:** Create a dictionary and iterate over keys.

```
information = {}
information['addressing'] = []
information['symbol'] = []
information['symbol2'] = []
information['opcode'] = []
information['bytes'] = []
information['cycles'] = []
key_list = list(information.keys())
for line in f:
    splitted = line.split()
    for i in range(0,len(splitted)):
        information[key_list[i]].append(splitted[i])
print(information)
```

Answer (score 0):

As already commented, you should remove all `index += 1` statements and leave just a single `index += 1` right at the end of the inner `for` loop. Or use `elif` intead of `if`.

Also, consider using [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#enumerate). There is no need to manually update the index variable:

```
# Example use of enumerate()
for line in f:
    for index, word in enumerate(line.split()):
        print(index, word)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to split each line at the longest block of `\s`:

```
import re
f = [re.split('\s+', i.strip('\n')) for i in open('filename.txt')]
final_data = [{a:list(i)} for a, i in zip(['addressing', 'symbol', 'symbol2', 'opcode', 'bytes', 'cycles'], zip(*f))]
```

Output:

```
[{'addressing': ['immediate', 'absolute']}, {'symbol': ['ADC', 'ADC']}, {'symbol2': ['#oper', 'oper']}, {'opcode': ['69', '6D']}, {'bytes': ['2', '3']}, {'cycles': ['2', '4']}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in `zip` function to transpose your rows of data into columns. The code below puts the data into a dictionary of tuples, with the field names as the keys. For this demo I've embedded the data into the script, since that's simpler than reading from a file, but it's easy to modify the code to read from a file.

```
file_data = '''\
immediate     ADC #oper     69    2     2
absolute      ADC oper      6D    3     4
'''.splitlines()

fields = 'addressing', 'symbol', 'symbol2', 'opcode', 'bytes', 'cycles'

values = zip(*[row.split() for row in file_data])
data = dict(zip(fields, values))
for k in fields:
    print(k, data[k])
```

**output**

```
addressing ('immediate', 'absolute')
symbol ('ADC', 'ADC')
symbol2 ('#oper', 'oper')
opcode ('69', '6D')
bytes ('2', '3')
cycles ('2', '4')
```

---

If you really want separate named variables, that's even easier, but as you can see it's more painful to work with.

```
file_data = '''\
immediate     ADC #oper     69    2     2
absolute      ADC oper      6D    3     4
'''.splitlines()

(addressing, symbol, symbol2, 
opcode, bytecode, cycles) = zip(*[row.split() for row in file_data])

print(addressing)
print(symbol)
print(symbol2)
print(opcode)
print(bytecode)
print(cycles)
```

**output**

```
('immediate', 'absolute')
('ADC', 'ADC')
('#oper', 'oper')
('69', '6D')
('2', '3')
('2', '4')
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're incrementing the index in every if block. So at the end of this block:

```
if index == 1:
     addressing.append(word)
     index += 1
     print(index)
```

The value of `index` is 2. Then when it hits `if index == 2:` that evaluates to True, adds that word to the second list, increments the index, and so on.

You *could* solve this by changing the inside for loop to `for index in range(1,6):` and stop incrementing `index` manually, but if you know that every line has 6 words it might be better to remove the inside for loop altogether and assign the words to the arrays manually.

```
for line in f:
     words = line.split() 
     addressing.append(words[0])
     symbol.append(words[1])
     ...etc
```